# Image, src, href in same span. How to locate? Webdriver, css locator

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I have tried to `click` on Google image in several ways but with no luck so far? Could you help, please?

```
<div class="AppLogos">
    <span class="iTunesLogo">
    <span class="GoogleLogo">
        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sportsdirect.sdapp&hl=en&utm_source=global_co&utm_medium=prtnr&utm_content=Mar2515&utm_campaign=PartBadge&pcampaignid=MKT-Other-global-all-co-prtnr-py-PartBadge-Mar2515-1" target="_top">
<img class="img-responsive" alt="Get it on Google Play" src="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/images/generic/en_badge_web_generic.png">
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You have mentioned I have tried to click on Google image in several ways but with no luck so far, Could you share HERE as well which have you tried so far??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment :-

> www.sportsdirect.com - I want to locate google app logo at startup (second popup)

(Assuming you'r using JAVA) Actually this pop is inside an `<iframe>`, that's why you are unable to locate this element. you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until this `<iframe>` present with the desire popup, then switch to that `<iframe>` before finding desire element as below :-

```
driver.get("http://www.sportsdirect.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize()

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

//now wait for pop visible with iframe and then switch to it
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='appadvert']")));

//now wait for desire element visible and enable to click
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.GoogleLogo > a"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you're using, but for C#:

```
IWebElement googleLogo = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("img-responsive"));
googleLogo.Click();
```

Should work, depending on the rest of the html, and whether the class appears elsewhere. XPath should work fine though.

Comment: Won 't work. Same class appears in "iTunesLogo" span. Xpath doesn't work as well. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Supermint, May be an XPATH along with parent tag may work. Did you get a chance to try it?

Comment: @Siva Thanks for reply. Xpath is: //*[@id='dnn_ctr13489121_HtmlModule_lblContent']/div/div[3]/span[2]/a/img How it should look with parent?

Comment: What's the error you're getting when trying to target it with XPath?

Comment: @Supermint, What i mean is `//span[@class='GoogleLogo']/a/img[@class='img-responsive']`. But if the XPATH you used doesn't work, the chances for the one i suggested to work also low.Please give a try.

Comment: @Josh Unable to find element. 'driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[@class='GoogleLogo']/a/img[@class='img-responsive']"));' doesn't work. [link](www.sportsdirect.com) - I want to locate google app logo at startup (second popup)

Comment: @Siva could you look at this, please?

Comment: @Supermint, do you work on downloaded `HTML` or on dynamically created `DOM`? Because if you make a web request to get an `HTML`, it may not be the same as you see it on your browser (`JavaScript` may add/remove elements, etc.)

Comment: @Supermint did you try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='GoogleLogo'‌​]/a/img[@class='img-‌​responsive']"));`